# CSS Help - Fixed top div, bottom div to fill the rest of the page - Bottom div background issue

Tags: css, html

I'm working on new site, and below is the draft code. Issue I’m facing is with bottom content div. Bottom div is fine with less content and it is filling the rest of the browser space. But if i put more content in bottom div (with page scroll), content div background is not continuing. Can anyone help me fixing this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#container {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: yellow;
}
#header {
height: 150px;
background: grey;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: brown;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cancel the absolute positioning and use the following CSS on `#content`:

```
#content {
  min-height: calc(100% - 150px);
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#container {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: yellow;
}
#header {
height: 150px;
background: grey;
}
#content {
min-height: calc(100% - 150px);
background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
<p>body content</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```